# Can you use DataSet and DataTables in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, cross-platform, portable-class-library

I am working on a project that relies on DataSet and DataTable. We wish to move into cross platform so are looking at Portable Class Libraries. However we cant find out how to use DataSet and DataTable in a portable class library. Are they available?

Maybe we should be moving away from DataSets and DataTables but we have what we have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the Dataset and DataTable are quite Windows specific Data structures, they would not be cross compatible, you may instead plan to serialize your result in to XML, Json, which would be available for use in all the platforms, thus achieving the inter-operability as expected, this would surely mean than in Windows you need a wrapper to de-serialize the XML / Json into relevant in memory object like DataTable

Answer (score 0):

In the *Shim* library that I have developed, there is basic and incomplete support for `DataSet`s and `DataTable`s.

*Shim* is a Portable Class Library which offers basic implementations of some types and methods that are available in .NET Framework but not in PCL. I developed *Shim* primarily to facilitate the porting of the [Accord.NET Framework](http://accord-framework.net/) to various platforms via PCL. *Accord.NET* relies to some extent on *ADO.NET* and I therefore implemented the *ADO.NET* classes and methods *Accord.NET* required in *Shim*.

You might want to take a look at *Shim* [here](https://github.com/cureos/shim) to see if it fits your needs. It is also available as [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/shim/2.0.0-alpha1) packages.

Comment: I've had a brief look at your library. I tried to import it into my PCL, but the using statements for System.ComponentModel, for example, dont seem to be resolved. Is there some setup required other than simply installing the package? I also had a look at your code, and I found quite a bit of these #if PCL
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("PCL");
#else  statements. Doesn't look like you are supporting PCL. I'm a bit confused

Comment: *Shim* uses the so-called [bait-and-switch](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) technique; the PCL library only provides declaration stubs of the supported types, methods and properties, whereas the actual implementations are provided in platform specific libraries that replace the PCL *Shim* when applied to an application. NuGet automatically applies the relevant instance of the *Shim* library depending on platform. If you need more help, please feel free to continue the discussion in the *Shim* Gitter chat room [here](https://gitter.im/cureos/shim).

Comment: Is it possible to databind the dataset to a controls item source?