# Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows)

Tags: c#

I have built a Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows) in VS2015.

I created a public class that having a data type with DataTable.

```
public class PNAWcfData
{
    public int CmdTimeout { get; set; }
    public string ErrMsg { get; set; }
    public DataTable DTResult { get; set; }
    public string XmlResult { get; set; }
}
```

However, I got error when build the solution.

> “The type or namespace name 'DataTable' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)”

I tried to add the using System.Data but still getting the same error. Also tried to add from **Project**->**Reference**, but it is telling that component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

DataTable classes are not available in the PCL. This is a duplicate of [Can you use DataSet and DataTables in a Portable Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596231/can-you-use-dataset-and-datatables-in-a-portable-class-library)

If you are using Xamarin, you may consider switching to Shared Project instead of PCL.

Comment: Too sad to know that the DataTable class is not available in PCL. I decided to choose the portable class library because I saw it can be used in cross platform (ios, android and windows). 
Anyway, thanks for answering my question! :)

Comment: you're welcome! Again, if you are using Xamarin, you can use shared projects for building cross platforms code, it almost "feels" like a library. PCL are too restrictive, to be useful one must create an interface for every real class required (like DataTable or even File) and a matching implementation in each target stack (ios, android and windows).